# How to setup Multi-page app with RequireJS with inline Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, requirejs

I'm trying to convert a project to use requirejs instead of the solution I have below. Currently I have a layout page that contains all of the scripts at the bottom of the page (except modernizr) before the  tag like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="@Links.Assets.Scripts.Libraries.modernizr_2_6_2_js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Page content goes here -->

    @RenderSection("PreScripts", false)
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="@Links.Assets.Scripts.Libraries.jquery_1_9_1_min_js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="@Links.Assets.Scripts.Libraries.jquery_namespace_js"></script>
    <script src="@Links.Assets.Scripts.Libraries.jquery_unobtrusive_ajax_js"></script>
    <script src="@Links.Assets.Scripts.Libraries.jquery_validate_js"></script>
    <script src="@Links.Assets.Scripts.Libraries.jquery_validate_unobtrusive_js"></script>
    <script src="@Links.Assets.Scripts.Libraries.jquery_timeago_js"></script>
    <script src="@Links.Assets.Scripts.Libraries.toastr_js"></script>
    <script src="@Links.Assets.Scripts.Views.Shared._master_js"></script>
    @RenderSection("PostScripts", false)

    @{
        var errorMessage = TempData[TempDataConstants.ErrorMessage] as string;
        var infoMessage = TempData[TempDataConstants.InfoMessage] as string;
        var successMessage = TempData[TempDataConstants.SuccessMessage] as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage)) {
            <script>
                var origTimeOut = toastr.options.timeOut;
                toastr.options.timeOut = 0;
                toastr.error(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(errorMessage)));
                toastr.options.timeOut = origTimeOut;
            </script>
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(successMessage)) {
            <script>
                var origTimeOut = toastr.options.timeOut;
                toastr.options.timeOut = 0;
                toastr.success(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(successMessage)));
                toastr.options.timeOut = origTimeOut;
            </script>
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoMessage)) {
            <script>
                var origTimeOut = toastr.options.timeOut;
                toastr.options.timeOut = 0;
                toastr.info(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(infoMessage)));
                toastr.options.timeOut = origTimeOut;
            </script>
        }
    }
</body>
```

In the individual pages that use this layout page I then populate the PostScripts section:

```
@section PostScripts {
    // Javascript that belongs to a single page goes here.
}
```

#### Problems

I've followed [this example](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage) but as you can see where I'm checking TempData on the server to see if its not null to popup a toastr message on the client. I"m not really sure the best way to go about doing this and have tried many things. Any ideas?